# API 2.0p5, Kanban Board, saving data on drop

Tags: rally

On my previous board (2.0p2), I had functionality that would autoassign the story to the current user if card was dropped into the InDev column.

I moved this code over, checked in the debugger that all the fields seem ok, but the card goes back to the original column.

Here is my listeners: of my cardBoardConfig

```
 listeners: {
     beforecarddroppedsave: function (cardboard, card) {
         var con = Rally.environment.getContext();
         //map the new state from on this card to the new state
         var kState = card.record.get(this.mappedFromField);
         var newState = this.fieldNameMap[card.record.get(this.mappedFromField)];
         card.record.set(this.mappedToField, newState);
          if (kState == 'In Dev') card.record.set('Owner', con.context.user)
    },
```

Everything seems to debug ok, but the card just goes back to orig column, and no data was saved.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That seems mostly right... One that that has changed is the signature of the event handler for that event:

    function(column, card, type) {}

What version of the SDK are you using?